# Getting a pixel's color from an image in a picturebox is not working

Tags: c#, colors, picturebox

I am trying to make an windows form application. In this application there is a picture box, and the user can choose a color by clicking on the color within the picture.

So I googled and tried some things, but it is not working correctly,

So I have this code for checking on which point the user clicks within the picture box and setting the `r`, `g` and `b`:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = MousePosition.X;
        y = MousePosition.Y;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", x, y));

        colorAtPoint = Properties.Resources.kleuren_rondje.GetPixel(x, y);

        r = colorAtPoint.R;
        g = colorAtPoint.G;
        b = colorAtPoint.B;         
    }
```

And I have this to check the color

```
        private void ColorChecker()
    {
        Graphics e = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));

        e.FillRectangle(myBrush, 1, 1, 100, 100);
    }
```

And this for checking if color is found en add in other picture box (for testing)

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorChecker();            
    }
```

I used methods from the internet but the `r`, `g` and `b` still gives `255`.
Does someone knows why or maybe an other way to check the `r`,`g`,`b` from an picture on an clicked point.

BTW, the `X` and the `Y` gives some point locations

Regards

Comment: What is `klueren_rondje` and how does the mouse location relate to it? It appears that it is an image resource which means that the `X` and `Y` mouse coordinates probably don't relate to a point on the image

Comment: kleuren_rondje is the name of the image file,
The x and the y points arent correctly. But cant find an other way to measure on witch point an user clicks whitin the picture box

Comment: and how does the mouse location relate to it? It appears that it is an image resource which means that the X and Y mouse coordinates probably don't relate to a point on the image

Comment: Another victim of CreateGraphics.  That's a temp canvas, easily destroyed by just minimizing your form.  Use the graphic object from the control's Paint event instead.

Answer (score 1):

MousePosition returns **screen** coords.  You need **CLIENT** coords.

Either convert it:

```
        Point pt = pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        x = pt.X;
        y = pt.Y;
```

...or use `MouseDown()` and its corresponding `e.X` and `e.Y`:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", x, y));

        // ...

    }
```

Comment: Both wont work:(
It wil get some r, g, b color but not the right color where clicked in the picture

Comment: What mode do you have the `SizeMode` property of your PictureBox set to?  If it isn't `AutoSize` or `Normal` then the coordinates of the mouse click won't map directly to the image...

Comment: I have it on stretchImg, all size modus gives the same result, some color but not the right one

Comment: There's your problem; put it on `Normal`...and why not just set the `BackColor` property of pictureBox2?

Comment: Setting the sizeMode to normal is a solution __only__ if it is an option. Otherwise you can __either__ calculate the streched click point, best taken in the MouseClick instead of the Click __or__ you can get the currently displayed bitmap using drawtobitmap..

Comment: That's a little too vague for us to help you.  We'd need to see some code and understand the setup a bit more...